# How to detect if a text file's column values aren't grouped?

Tags: bash

We receive a tab-delimited text file from a vendor whose records should be grouped by a particular column.  I need to scan it to see if that's the case or if outliers are in there.

For example, this file is fine (let's call it `vendor.tsv`), because the 'Book 61' entries are all together:

```
+---------+------------------+
|  Title  |      Author      |
+---------+------------------+
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
| Book 34 | Amanda Jones     |
| Book 87 | Heather Bancroft |
+---------+------------------+
```

..however this is not ok:

```
+---------+------------------+
|  Title  |      Author      |
+---------+------------------+
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
| Book 34 | Amanda Jones     |
| Book 87 | Heather Bancroft |
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
+---------+------------------+
```

All I need to check in this case is the first column, there's no chance the same title would have different authors in this scenario.

Ideally I'd like to know the book title with the a problem (`Book 61` above), and the first line where it occurs (line 5 above, not including the header)

I know a little bit of `awk` but am not sure if that is the right tool here, nor am I sure how to use it to check whether non-consecutive lines have identical values in a column.

Comment: I see you started using the ascii tables... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your file to raw tsv file:

```
Title   Author
Book 61 Joe Smith
Book 61 Joe Smith
Book 34 Amanda Jones
Book 87 Heather Bancroft
Book 87 Heather Bancroft
Book 61 Joe Smith
Book 87 Heather Bancroft
```

Then this would help:

```
$ awk -F$'\t' 'NR==1{next} (a[$1]++) && b != $1 {printf "Line %d: %s\n", NR,$0}; {b=$1}' vendor.tsv 
Line 7: Book 61 Joe Smith
Line 8: Book 87 Heather Bancroft
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` and `sort`:

```
cat vendor.tsv
+---------+------------------+
|  Title  |      Author      |
+---------+------------------+
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
| Book 34 | Amanda Jones     |
| Book 87 | Heather Bancroft |
| Book 61 | Joe Smith        |
+---------+------------------+
< vendor.tsv awk -F'|' 'NR>3{print $2, $3}' | sort -c -k1,1
sort: -:3: disorder:  Book 34   Amanda Jones
```

PS: This will actually give you the line below the problem, I hope it works as well for you